# There are not a error_log file

Tags: php, error-log

I just got a VPS, it's my first.
The problem is the server is not doing put the error_log on the root domain directories, I'm having any 500 error but doesn't show the error_log php. Even I delete a ; to generate an error, but it doesn't show the error_log.

I've checked the php ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
error_log = error_log
```

But the strange is on PHPinfo I saw this

```
error_log   /home/durweb/logs/dur-web_com.php.error.log /home/durweb/logs/dur-web_com.php.error.log
```

I don't know what to do
I appreciate your help

Comment: Did you check `phpinfo()` to make sure its using the `php.ini` file that you are looking at

Comment: Did you check the file `/home/durweb/logs/dur-web_com.php.error.log` ?

Comment: I just checked now, here is /home/durweb/logs/dur-web_com.php.error.log Now, How can I change this path?

Comment: By configuring the [`error_log`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) setting. This _can_ be set at runtime, but then it obviously won't work for any parse errors that prevent your script from running in the first place. So if you want those logged as well, you need to configure it outside of the script.